# Login anonymous behaviour even though the user exist it shows invalid user

Tags: django, authentication

**views.py**
'

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

            else:
                return HttpResponse("inactive")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Someone tried to login and failed")
    else:

        return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html', {})
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron">
     <form action="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
         <input type = "text" name="Username" placeholder="enter">
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input type = "password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">

         <input type = "submit" name ="" value = "LOGIN">

     </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In django admin the users are registered and are in database but when i login it shows Someone tried to login and failed .

**I have to submit this by midnight need help noob here.**

Comment: How did you *register* a user?

Comment: Not sure if this is it but your form's username input has `name="Username"` with a capital `U`.

Comment: voodoo-burger thanks that was the issue !!!! :))

Comment: voodoo-burger need help on another question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63126246/12472317