# no reverse matching at / and crawler is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, django-views, backend

I am trying to make a codeforces crawler and I am just adding user authentication in the somehow failed to implement. `Reverse not match and crawler is not a  registered namespace` is the error I'm getting. I don't know what files exactly are needed to put here so please ask me I will post them if you need it. I'm just a beginner and I need help.

**crawler/urls.py**

```py
app_name = 'crawler'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('formpage/',views.search_form_view , name='searchform'),
    path('formpage/<str:handle>',views.person, name= 'person'),
    path('user_login/',views.user_login,name ="user_login"),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name="logout"),
]
```

**base.html**

```html
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'crawler:index'%}">Crawler</a>
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'crawler:searchform'%}">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'crawler : logout'%}">Log Out</a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'crawler :user_login'%}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
{% block body_block %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

**views.py**

```py
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse(reverse('index'))
```

**webcrawler/urls.py**

```py
app_name = 'crawler'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('crawler.urls',namespace= "crawler")),
]
```

Comment: Consider adding a specific error / stack trace that you are encountering. It is difficult to diagnose the issue at hand without an error.

Answer (score 0):

A two-part answer here.

**No reverse match at /**

The point is that, in both your main and app urls.py, you registered both URLs to be '', which means that there will be a match at (empty string) but won't be one at '/'. To fix this, simply add '/' to the *main* urls.py as it's a better practice.

**Crawler is not a registered namespace**

As you call an URL, it should be `{% url 'crawler:index' %}` or `{% url 'crawler:searchform' %}` or something because crawler is the main namespace but there are multiple URLs under it so you need to pass an additional parameter after your crawler namespace.

Comment: i worked on it but still getting codeforces is not  a registered namespacce

Comment: Because you never registered it (my bad for thinking that you meant 'crawler'). Which URL do you want to be named 'codeforces'? If you have one, again, I can't see it

Comment: ah sorry i mispelled crawler :( as codeforces problem is  solved thank u